# How to convert a numeric value into a time format inside a formula that also contains a string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have a "mixed" formula (containing numbers and text) and I need to convert the numeric values into a time format.

Here is my formula:

```
=count(J8:J11)*2/24&" / "&sum(K8:K11)
```

And here is the resulting cell value:

```
0.333333333333333 / 0.204861111111111
```

What I want to see is:

```
8:00 / 4:55
```

How can I transform these long numbers into a time format as such?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`TEXT` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) in your formula:

```
=TEXT(COUNT(J8:J11)*2/24,"H:mm")&" / "&TEXT(SUM(K8:K11), "H:mm")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we could try finding out why. If yes, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.